# What does "card" and "make up" here mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "card" and "make up" here mean?

> {}It was heralded by a notice from Dale Owen, dated January 5,
> to the effect that evidence had been laid before him which compelled
> him to withdraw his previous expressions of confidence in the
> Holmeses. A similar **card** was issued by Dr. Child. Writing to Olcott, who
> after his Eddy investigation was recognized as an authority, Dale Owen
> said: "I believe they have been latterly playing us false, which may
> be only supplementing the genuine with the spurious, but it does cast
> a doubt on last summer's manifestations, so that I shall probably not
> use them in my next book on Spiritualism. It is a loss, but you and
> Mr. Crookes have amply **made it up**."

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-up_1#make-up_1__5

Comment: Where did you find this text?

Comment: What does the *{}* represent? I've never seen it used like this before, and I don't understand its function. I can only think it's supposed to represent a paragraph indent. If so, you could use a series of non-breaking space characters (Unicode U+00A0). I normally use 6 for such an indent on this site.

Comment: After some searching, the text seems to come from Arthur Conan Doyle's [*The History of Spiritualism*](https://www.worldspirituality.org/eddy-brothers.html), in an essay called "Eddy Brothers and the Holmses." If I look at the actual text, that's not how the paragraph starts. Two things to note. If you are quoting text, you can start in the middle of a paragraph without signalling that something has been omitted. However, if you *do* want to indicate an omission, you normally use an ellipsis (…), not curly brackets. (At least as far as I've ever known.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Card" I would guess reflects the same meaning as "notice" in the previous sentence.

"Made it up", in the above, appears to mean that those two individuals have made contributions which compensate for the losses due to "they" (whoever they are) "playing us false" (ie, fabricating claims).